# redirect with variable using .htaccess

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect from:

```
http://my-site.com/index.php?ean={any_number}
```

for example: `http://my-site.com/index.php?ean=123`

to:

```
http://my-site.com/b={any_number}
```

for example: `http://my-site.com/b=123`

Note that I need to use the `REDIRECT` function, not the `RewriteRule`.

Any ideas?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Is using PHP to redirect in _index.php_ an option or does it have to be via _.htaccess_?

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried yourself? What is the content of your `.htaccess`?

Comment: what you have try?  and why only `RESIRECT`?

Comment: using PHP to redirect in `index.php` an option, but I prefer the `.htaccess` option.

Comment: I have tried `RewriteRule` options, but i need the `REDIRECT` function.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^index.php$
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^ean=([0-9]+)$
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://my-site.com/b=%1 [R,L]
```

Comment: is it redirecting to anything or not at all

Comment: I need the `REDIRECT` function, while you use the `RewriteRule` function. Any way, it doesn't work. But thank you!

Comment: @ins0, can I use it in my `.htaccess`? It seems that it should be configured trough the apache settings, but I have not access to those settings.

Comment: did you set RewriteEngine on ?

Comment: are u sure that ``.htaccess`` files are ignored from your directory? try place a ``.htaccess`` file with random words in your public folder, if u get a ``Internal Server Error`` Message you can use ``.htaccess`` files otherwise such wide redirects are really nasty to implement

Comment: @ins0 The `.htaccess` does work. What I meant is if the function that you suggested me could work in `.htaccess`?

Comment: did it redirect to any thing or nothing at all ?

Comment: no i won't work because ``RedirectMatch`` is from the Apache Mod ``mod-alias`` and can't handle query redirects where ``RewriteRule`` is from ``mod-rewrite`` and had ``Conditions`` which would work. if you can't use rewrite your only option is to hardcore code in every php file this redirect

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP, you can perform a redirect using `header()`.

---

```
<?php 
//--- index.php snippet ---

if (isset($_GET['ean'])) {
  header("Location: http://yoursite.com/b=".intval(trim($_GET['ean'])));
  exit(0);
}
```

---

If you were redirecting based on a URI and not a parameter, you could use [RedirectMatch](http://www.askapache.info//2.3/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) to perform the redirect in *.htaccess* (i.e., *yoursite.com/ean/12345*).

The code for *.htaccess* would be something like the following:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /ean/(.*) /b=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

So, finally I have decided to redirect with the `header(Location: www.your-site.com)` function in `PHP`. Thank you.